# clear textbox after post to server with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a form submission to the server and its working perfectly, but the issue is after the post is submitted to the server, the textbox is not clear even though I've set that state to be empty

CONTAINER COMPONENT

```
state = {
  newCar: '',
}

      setNewCar= (newCar) => {
        this.setState({ newCar: newCar })
        }

        newCar = () => {
          const api = create({
            baseURL: 'url.com/apis',
            headers: {'Accept': 'application/json',  
                      'header': '1',
                      'header2': '2'}
          });
          const self = this;
          self.setState({showCommentLoader: true });
          api.post('cars/'+'/new_car',{
            'car_name': this.state.carName
          }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
          self.setState({showCommentLoader: false, newCar:"" });

           })
        }
```

VIEW

```
 <TextInput
   onChangeText={setNewCar} 
   underlineColor="#36a"
   style={{backgroundColor:'#fff', width:'90%', bottom:10}}
 />
```

Comment: Where is the `value` property of `<TextInput ...>`? Just missing from the example of code?

Comment: yes please, i forgot

Answer (score 1):

Get the ref of your TextInput like this:

```
<TextInput
   ref={(textInput) => this.inputRef= textInput}
   onChangeText={setNewCar} 
   underlineColor="#36a"
   style={{backgroundColor:'#fff', width:'90%', bottom:10}}
/>
```

After post is submitted, do the following to clear the textinput:

```
this.inputRef.clear();
```